# How to create middlawere for mongoose queries

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the legacy backend. This backend use mongoose. There is collection "Users". This collection has "email" field.

I was faced with the bug - email is case sensitive. I want to save all new emails in lower case. For this I've modified "Users" schema with this:

```
email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true
}
```

But also backend has a lot of places with things like:

```
user.find({email: some_case_unnormalized_email})
```

or this:

```
user.findOne({email: some_case_unnormalized_email})
```

I don't want to modify that places to:

```
user.find({email: some_case_unnormalized_email.toLowerCase()})
```

Instead, I want to create some middleware for "Users" schema like:

```
UsersSchema.middleware('any_query', queryObject => {
    if (queryObject.email) {
        queryObject.email = queryObject.email.toLowerCase();
    }
});
```

How to do that?

Comment: Mongoose has some great documentation about their middleware ecosystem http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: it is not something that I need and there is not example how to replace query params

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko look for `schema.pre('find', ...)`

Comment: @robertklep I don't want to use schema.pre('find, schema.pre('findOne etc. I want something like schema.pre('any_query

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko how is that different from `schema.pre('find', ...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use pre save hook to modify any property**

```
UserSchema.pre('find', function(next){
    var query = this;
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(query, null, 2));
    // update your query here
    next();
})

UserSchema.pre('findOne', function(next){
    var query = this;
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(query, null, 2));
    // update your query here
    next();
})
```

Comment: The question is about querying, not saving.